# Как установить несколько Live CD на флешку?

Tags: usb, grub

Есть:

1. Флешка на 8 гб, разбитая на 4 раздела (FAT32 для использования по назначению, NTFS для Alkid live CD и два ext2 раздела для Ubuntu Live DVD и ESET Rescue Disk)
2. Все перечисленные выше образы.

Нужно получить флешку, при загрузке с которой появлялось меню (grub2, или любого другого загрузчика) с выбором нужного live cd.

Пробовал распаковать каждый из образов в нужный раздел и установить grub из-под Ubuntu. Grub устанавливается и даже загружается, но при установке находит только ОСи на жестком диске, соответственно ни один из live cd я загрузить не могу. Исправить grub.cfg вручную не получилось... Может кто-нибудь знает решение?

Comment: Вопрос отправлял с телефона, текст вопроса не отправился.Итак, у меня есть флешка, разбитая на 4 раздела и 3 образа: Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, Alkid Live CD/USB и ESET Rescue Disk. Файлы каждого образа извлечены в корень соотв. раздела (первый раздел пуст). Как сделать для них меню мультизагрузки. Пробовал GRUB2, но он видит только операционные системы на жёстком диске...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Мультизагрузочная флешка MultiSystem: Ubuntu customized, Clonezilla и Windows 7 на одном USB](http://ubuntism.ru/2011/03/multisystem2/).

Answer (score 2):

[Мультизагрузочный USB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Comment: Спасибо, но кажется, это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Пожалуйста, прочитайте комментарий к этому вопросу.

Comment: > 3 образа: Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, Alkid Live CD/USB и ESET Rescue Disk. Файлы каждого образа извлечены в корень соотв. раздела (первый раздел пуст). Как сделать для них меню мультизагрузкиКак по мне, так то что нужно. Вот так попробуйте http://dpk.itc.ua/content/35140

Comment: @gurzufnet, у меня несколько разделов на флешке. А насколько я знаю, из-под Windows можно работать только с первым разделом флешки.

Comment: Alkid будет работать с первого раздела. Ubunta и ей подобные с любого другого, или из отдельной директории в первом разделе, grub в mbr флешки.

Answer (score 0):

Установи [Grub4DOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/).Там в `menu.lst` пропиши путь к образам.